# SQL: how to select only repeated values from same column?

Tags: sql

!!! there is a way to solve this problem using HAVING, but is there other simple way of doing it without use of HAVING ?

let's say I have a table t1 which has got two relations a and b.

```
-a  b
-1  2
-2  1
-3  4
-4  9
-8  5
-5  2
-6  5
```

how do I print only the cases from column B that are repeating (in this case: 2 and 5)?

Comment: why won't you use having? What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Comment: `HAVING` is for exactly this purpose - what's wrong with using it?

Comment: Can you show us how you achieved this with `HAVING`? And why do you not want to use `HAVING`?

Comment: it's just a task which I thought up for myself. a brain teaser, of sorts.

Comment: @Daniel Kelley-I just posted HAVING example...

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want a `HAVING` clause, then you can use a subquery:

```
select t1.a, t1.b
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select count(*) tot, b
  from yourtable
  group by b
) t2
  on t1.b = t2.b
where t2.tot > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/920b3/11).

The subquery will be used to get the count of each `b` value.  You then join the result to your table and filter out any records that have a count greater than 1.

This gives the result:

```
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 |
```

Comment: @otGO happy to help.  If this answers your question, feel free to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already nice examples... Example with HAVING:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT col_a t1
   FROM stack_test
 ) a,
 (
 SELECT col_b t2
   FROM stack_test
  GROUP BY col_b
  HAVING Count(*) > 1
 ) b
 WHERE t1 = t2
 /

 SQL>

  T1   T2
  -------
  2     2
  5     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with either aggregation or joins.  I prefer the former, but here is one method:

```
select *
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.b = t.b and t2.a <> t.a)
```

This, of course, assumes that the `a` values differ when the `b` values are the same.